# Json_encode() подставляет лишние символы (массив в кавычках)

Tags: json, javascript, php

вот тут выбрал ключевые строки из кода, на котором видно как образуются оба массива:

что-то тут глючит функция вставки кода, никак не вставить нормально, вот ссылка: http://mysticpaste.com/view/wcfs0yKMfl?11 (тут текст)

если вывести в джаваскрипте оба, то результат будет такой:

> "[[1,\"one\",\"test\"],[2,\"two\",null],[3,\"three\",null],[4,\"four\",\"temp\"]]"
>
> [[1,"one","test"],[2,"two","null"],[3,"three","null"],[4,"four","test2"]]

почему в первом случае весь массив в кавычках (а так же экранирование внутри) и как это всё убрать, что бы было как второй вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите скобки в выводе. Строка воспринимается как текст, соответственно все кавычки экранируются.

```
var myData1 = <?php echo $json; ?>; //get data
```